# Do the characters in the classic X-Men arcade game have different fighting capabilities?

Tags: arcade, x-men

I recently purchased the classic Konami X-Men Arcade Game for the iPhone and have been playing through it. I have noticed that some characters are easier to control and fight with than others. For example, it seems like Nightcrawler can handle front and back basic attacks more deftly than, for instance, Dazzler. Using the same playing technique, the fighting outcome differs from character to character. Are the six playable characters really different, or is it just my own subconscious bias towards Nightcrawler that makes me believe he is the best?

**EDIT** I am referencing basic attacks, not their super special mutant powers. As in, punching/throwing/jumping/kicking/jump kicking ability.

Comment: Different in terms of basic attacks? Since their super attacks are definitely unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each mutant has similar basic punches, throws, and attacks, but each has a unique mutant power to destroy their foes. Cyclops uses an optic blast, Storm calls a tornado to kills enemies, Nightcrawler teleports and destroys enemies on screen, etc... Mutant powers are the only things that truly distinguish one X-Man from the next, as all other attacks are the same for each character.